# Why ordinary user cannot use chgrp/chown

Tags: linux, command

```
-bash-3.2$ man chgrp | head -1
CHGRP(1)                         User Commands                        CHGRP(1)
-bash-3.2$ man chown | head -1   
CHOWN(1)                         User Commands                        CHOWN(1)
```

following content is from 'man 7 man':

```
1 Commands
            Those commands that can be executed by the user from within a shell.
8 System management commands
            Commands like mount(8), many of which only root can execute.
```

Why CHGRP(1)/CHOWN(1) cannot be used by ordinary user? In my understanding, CHGRP(8)/CHOWN(8) cannot be used by ordinary user.

Comment: Is your question: why the `chown` command is in the section 1, not 8 of the man page?

Answer (score 1):

Letting non-root user to use `chown` or `chgrp` would have many problems.

1. If user were able to `chown otheruser ownfile`, then after that, he would not be able to access his own file anymore - not good.
2. If some evil user hijacked your account, he would be able to change permissions on your files such that they are now owned by other user: like evil user or www user. Then, it would be trivial to steal your data.

Comment: Hi, but:1 Commands
            Those commands that can be executed by the user from within a shell.

Comment: it makes no difference - shell command `chown` is nothing more than thin wrapper that calls `chown` syscall.

Answer (score 0):

If any user could successfully call the [chown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html) syscall (e.g. thru `chrgrp` and `chown` commands) on files not belonging to him, the user-based access protection provided by the Linux kernel would be useless. A malicious user would change ownership of every file whose access is limited to him

Of course, the user could execute the `chown` command (e.g. by typing `/usr/bin/chown` *`file`*) but if called from an ordinary user these commands will fail (and have a non-zero exit code) because the underlying `chown(2)` syscall would fail.

NB: as documented, an ordinary user may `chgrp` to some group he belongs to.

Comment: Hi, but:1 Commands
            Those commands that can be executed by the user from within a shell.

Comment: Being able to invoke a command does not imply that the command is always running successfully !

Answer (score 0):

All users can use `chgrp` change the group of a file they own to other groups they are a member of. Try this, replacing the group name `lpadmin` with any second group that are in:

```
touch t; ls -l t; chgrp lpadmin t; ls -l t
```

The *before* and *after* calls to `ls` will show that the group changed.